# ios UICollectionView cell selecting and deselecting issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, xcode9

Im using UIcollection view as my tabbar
when I scroll collection view horizontally previous selected cell will not deselect when i select new one

this is my code to change colour when i select a cell and deselect a cell

```
  var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath = []
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? 
   BottomCollectionViewCell {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
   }

  if let preViousSelectedcell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: 
  selectedIndexPath) as? BottomCollectionViewCell {

     preViousSelectedcell.contentView.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple
     preViousSelectedcell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
 }
 selectedIndexPath = indexPath


}
```

Comment: use `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: i used that already but nothing changed.I think index path is changing when i scroll the view.

Comment: Can you please update your answer, showing how you've used it?

Comment: @Sath.Dev deselect will be called if you click on a cell which is already selected not if you are selecting any other cell. And do some research you'll get many answers on this.

Answer (score 6):

while scrolling cells are reused that time `cellForItemAt` will call so you need to change some modification in your code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 selectedIndexPath = indexPath
 YOUR_COLLECTION_VIEW.reloadData()
}
```

and add below lines inside your `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

```
if indexPath ==  selectedIndexPath {
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor=UIColor.purple
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
} else {
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you, works for me,  got tangled in didselect and diddeselect collection view, now resolved