# Collection view set radio button image on first index and on did select change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have collection view with 3 or 4 items of data. Each cell has one radio image. When app load first time, i need first index radio button image to br selected , and if it tap on any cell that cell image should be turn to selected radio image.And previous one should change to un selected radio image.

i have handled this in my cell for row method :

```
let isFirstData = (nameData.name == self.nameObjects[0].name) ? true : false
cell.set(dataSource: ["isSelected": isFirstData] as [String: AnyObject])
```

Here `nameData` is my single data which i pass to my cell for row method. And i am setting data Source that will handle my data source in my cell.

So now in did select how can i change it.?

And i am not satisfied  with my cell for row method code to handle it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks, 
Rohit

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545220/ios-uicollectionview-cell-selecting-and-deselecting-issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to override in UICollectionViewCell class this this method.

```
 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: true)
   if selected{
     set selected image
   } else {
    set unselected image
  }
    }
```

After this your need to to call Highlighted method in VC class
and set selected image their.

Comment: but at first load how can i set my first data to be selected ?

Comment: in hightlighted method you need to set image at indexPath[0]

Comment: UICollectionView does not have setSelected method, turky should override isSelected property as I mentioned.

Comment: @emrepun is right setSelected is for tableView. you need to handle it by isSelect, and didSelectItemAt.

Comment: @emrepun can you answer this?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59776362/1769448

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direction for you, let me know if you cannot implement it:

Have a method in your cell file and then override `isSelected` property of `UICollectionViewCell`, then if `isSelected = true`, call your method with a parameter value of true to select radio button image and if it is false call your method with a parameter value of false to de select radio button image and update UI accordingly.

Then In `cellForRowAt` method or in `willDisplayCellAt` method of `UICollectionView` later on, select the first item on first start up with `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` method. When the collection view is first initialized, it will show the first item as selected, and then when you select another cell, it will update UI for all cells accordingly since you overrided `isSelected` property and call methods there.

How to select the first item when cells are displayed (There could be other ways of doing it as well):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
    }
}
```

Please note that, this will select first item for all sections, this might cause problems if you have more than 1 section in your `UICollectionView`

Or if you are sure your `collectionView` will always have data available when view is loaded, you can do the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left)
```

Comment: i am new to the dev, not able to understnand the process, any code would help to learn and understand

Comment: how can i set the first cell as selected  as default ?. I am not able to understand that